# Ffmpeg rebroadcast icecast stream and disconnect on silence

Tags: ffmpeg, stream, icecast, disconnect, mplayer

Currently, I'm using a combination of the Windows version of butt and VLC Media Player in order to rebroadcast an icecast stream from a remote icecast server to my local icecast server, whilst disconnecting whenever a certain duration of silence is detected.

I would really prefer if there would be an easier way to do this on linux from the command line, so that it can run 24/7 without me having to constantly fix the VLC stream player every so often.

I need a way for if silence is detected on the stream, it disconnects the relay and will reconnect whenever audio is detected again.

As I've said before, I've been successfully using butt and VLC Media Player on Windows to do this, however would prefer a linux alternative.

Comment: Can you clarify why the requirement for disconnecting the local connection? What is the overall use case you are trying to address

Comment: I run an internet radio station and one of our syndicated programs, specifically the morning show, is fed into our automation software via their icecast stream. However, their icecast stream doesn't disconnect whenever the show ends or whenever we're supposed to air our spots. Instead, it just goes to a period of 5 seconds of silence before the time is given to disconnect and then go to our local automation. I need something that can disconnect the local icecast server since the software I use for playout doesn't have a silence detector built in to it, but will stop playing upon source drop.

Comment: To clarify, I need something that can take a remote icecast stream, rebroadcast it over my local icecast server and disconnect whenever silence is detected, and then reconnect when there is audio again. Icecast has the relay feature built in, however it doesn't drop the source when silence is detected.